# Как сделать медленно плавающий фон?

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, uwp

Как сделать эффект для `image`, чтобы, например, широкая картинка медленно плыла слева направо, или сверху вниз?

Comment: запустить таймер и в обработчике двигать image

Comment: @Stack а разве это не будет выглядеть рывками? Нужна плавная анимация, а не дёрганная.

Comment: _"это не будет выглядеть рывками?"_ -- если двигать на небольшое расстояние, то рывков не будет. а в xaml есть специальные теги/классы для анимации. см. Storyboard https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.animation.storyboard

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Создаете анимацию

```
    <Storyboard x:Name="ImageMotionStoryboard">
        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ImageTranslateTransform"
                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="X"
                         EnableDependentAnimation="True"
                         RepeatBehavior="Forever"
                         AutoReverse="True"
                         From="0"
                         To="400"
                         Duration="0:0:6.5"/>
    </Storyboard>
```

для своей картинки

```
    <Image x:Name="image"
           HorizontalAlignment="Left"
           Stretch="None"
           Source="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/554718807173128192/U05F6wS9.jpeg">
        <Image.RenderTransform>
            <TranslateTransform x:Name="ImageTranslateTransform"/>
        </Image.RenderTransform>
    </Image>
```

И в удобном месте запускаете свою анимацию

```
        ImageMotionStoryboard.Begin();
```

**UPDATE:**
пример работы

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Огромнейшее спасибо вам!